# How does custom lock screens from play market work

Tags: java, android

I'm developing lock screen for android. I made everything except disabling home button and square button.  I only know how not to allow press back button. It's pretty easy. I searched some info. Here is some attempts that don't work for home button:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
}
```

I know how to make app fullscreen or how to hide navigation bar. But it is not what I want.

Here is the example of lock screen. It is `CM Locker`. Home button and sqare button don't work there, but it is touchable and visible.It's exactly what I need

[image]

**How can I reach that fuctionality?** Maybe try to make a lock screen as a launcher. But think it's gonna be a wrong way. Also I assume that the app can draw over other apps. But it's not gonna prevent going back. **Please give some advice**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try disable the keyguard? add the following code to your `onAttachedToWindow`.

```
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock keyguardLock = keyguardManager
            .newKeyguardLock(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
```

Comment: @Zhambul make sure the all your code is before the super call `super.onAttachedToWindow();`.